# Как методом onClick перейти на новую страницу

Tags: reactjs

Как можно сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку sign up перходило на новую страницу с компонентаммы для регистрации,
и можно ли сделать это через вызов класса?

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

 class RegistrationForm extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
this.state={
  email:'',
Password:''
} ;
this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.handlePasswordChange=this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
console.log('form is submitted. Email value is',this.state.email);
 }

handleEmailChange(event){
console.log('email was changet',event.target.value);
this.setState({email:event.target.value})
}
handlePasswordChange(event){
console.log('Password was changet',event.target.value);
this.setState({Password:event.target.value})
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.hendleSubmit}>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="E-mail"
value={this.state.email}
onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
/>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="Password"
value={this.state.Password}
  onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
/>
   </form>
   <button className="square" onClick={this.SingUpForm}>Sing In</button>
   <button>Sing Up</button>

   </div>
  );
}
}
export default RegistrationForm;

import React,{Component} from 'react';

class SingUpForm extends Component{
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state={
  First_name:'',
  Second_name:'',
  email:'',
   Password1:'',
  Password2:''
  } ;
 this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 this.handleFirst_nameChange = this.handleFirst_nameChange.bind(this);
 this.handleSecond_nameChange = this.handleSecond_nameChange.bind(this);
 this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
 this.handlePassword1Change = this.handlePassword1Change.bind(this);
 this.handlePassword2Change = this.handlePassword2Change.bind(this);
 }
 handleSubmit(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 console.log('form is submitted. Email value is',this.state.email);
 }
 handleFirst_nameChange(event){
  console.log('form is submitted. First_name value is',event.target.value);
 this.setState({First_name:event.target.value})
 }
 handleSecond_nameChange(event){
  console.log('form is submitted. Second_name value is',event.target.value);
  this.setState({Second_name:event.target.value})
 }
  handleEmailChange(event){
  console.log('email was changet',event.target.value);
  this.setState({email:event.target.value})
 }
 handlePassword1Change(event){
  console.log('form is submitted.Pasvord value is',event.target.value);
  this.setState({Password1:event.target.value})
 }
 handlePassword2Change(event){
  console.log('form is submitted.Pasvord value is',event.target.value);
  this.setState({Password2:event.target.value})
}
 render(){
 return(
  <div>
<form onSubmit={this.hendleSubmit}>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="First name"
value={this.state.First_name}
onChange={this.handleFirst_nameChange}
/>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="Second name"
value={this.state.Second_name}
onChange={this.handleSecond_nameChange}
/>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="E-mail"
value={this.state.email}
onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
/>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="Password"
value={this.state.Password1}
onChange={this.handlePassword1Change}
/>
<input
type="text"
placeholder="Password"
value={this.state.Password2}
onChange={this.handlePassword2Change}
/>
</form>

<button>Sing Up</button>
  </div>
  );
 }
 }
export default SingUpForm;
```

Comment: Вопрос "можно ли сделать это через вызов класса?" уточните, не ясно, что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку sign up перходило на
>   новую страницу с компонентаммы для регистрации.

Один из вариантов.

- Перенести кнопку в форму, тогда она будет по умолчанию вызывать
  событие `submbit` у формы.
- Повесьте на событие onClick кнопки подобную функцию (доработайте под свои нужды, это лишь пример).

```js
function handleClick(){
    let form = document.querySelector("formID")
    form.method = 'GET';
    form.submit();
}
```

По умолчанию, когда у формы срабатывает событие `submit`, то, исходя из введенных в инпуты данных, форма генерирует querystring (см. подробней про URL) и применяет его к текущему URL (`site.com/?key=value`), если у формы указан атрибут `action`, то генерация нового URLа будет происходить не относительно текущего адреса, а относительно адреса, указанного в action. Это поведение, если необходимо, можно изменить, используя `preventDefault()` для события `submit` формы.